# why i can not convert .py that conatain pytesseract.pytesseract to .exe file

Tags: python, arabic, python-tesseract

I need to extract arabic text from image so I use `pytesseract.pytesseract` and it works in `PyCharm` editor but when I convert `.py` file to `.exe` file it not work.

```
def do():
    try:
        global scr
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'  # th path of tesseract
        img_entered = Image.open(nu.get())
        text_ = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_entered, lang='ara')
        scr.insert(index=tk.END,chars=text_)
        nu.set("")

    except:
        messagebox.showerror("error","لا يمكن استخراج نص من هذا الملف")
```

When i run `.exe` file it gives me the correct GUI but when it needs to convert image to text it always do the except from the `do()` function.

My questions:

1. how can i solve this ?
2. is there are any another way to convert image to text ?

Comment: first remove `try/except`, create `.exe` and run `.exe` to see full error message. And when you see full error message then you will know what is the problem. And then you can use Google to find solution for this problem. Without full error message nobody can help you.

Comment: I can only guess that you have to manually add `tesseract.exe` to your project because tool used to convert `.py` to `.exe` doesn't add it automatically. But only if you see full error message then you will know if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

before running the converted .exe  file comes from .py file ,

the tesseract.exe file must be installed in pc in the folder that you define in .py file here in my case is C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe